# How to access the child of preceding sibling from current's node ancestor in xslt 1.0

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a question regarding on using Xpath axis to get a node value from the preceding sibling of the current node's ancestor. On the following code, let's say I'm currently in "g_place id="3"" of group id="1" . My goal is to compare all the nodes "g_place" of group id="0" with the node "g_place id="3".

```
<conflict id="22">
    <group id="0">
      <g_priority>1</g_priority>
      <g_transition id="9"/>
      <g_place id="2">
        <g_arc id="12"/>
      </g_place>
      <g_place id="3">
        <g_arc id="13"/>
      </g_place>
    </group>
    <group id="1">
      <g_priority>2</g_priority>
      <g_transition id="10"/>
      <g_place id="3">
        <g_arc id="14"/>
      </g_place>
      <g_place id="4">
        <g_arc id="15"/>
      </g_place>
    </group>
    <group id="2">
      <g_priority>3</g_priority>
      <g_transition id="11"/>
      <g_place id="4">
        <g_arc id="16"/>
      </g_place>
      <g_place id="5">
        <g_arc id="17"/>
      </g_place>
    </group>
  </conflict>
```

I already tried a solution but it doesn't work

```
 <xsl:for-each select="key('conflict', $conflict_id)/group">
    <xsl:sort select="g_priority" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
       <xsl:text>          If </xsl:text>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:for-each select="./g_place">
         <xsl:variable name="place_id" select="@id" />
         <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::group[1]/g_place/attribute::id = $place_id">
            <xsl:text>          Elsif </xsl:text>
         </xsl:when>     
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>          If </xsl:text>
         </xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>      
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use

```
<xsl:for-each select="./g_place">
```

you are now under the context of `g_place`. To access the preceding `group`, you can use

```
<xsl:when test="../preceding-sibling::group[1]/g_place/attribute::id = $place_id">
```

`../` meaning `parent::*`. Or, you can use the `preceding` axis

```
<xsl:when test="preceding::group[1]/g_place/attribute::id = $place_id">
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer and it didn't work. The goal is to generate a file and when I try to generate it, the folder where the file will go doesn't have the file. The way the code is built is that, when processing, the first group will fall in the when test="position() = 1". After that, the following groups will fall in otherwise and will be processed, comparing with the previous group. Now, I'm not sure if the sort thing is causing the problem .Thank you.

Comment: Please see this link (http://xsltransform.net/6qjwabP). I have made a minimal XSL for your reference.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your effort! I discovered why the file didn't appear on the folder. If you look closely there is a "choose" that is missing a '/' (second counting from the bottom). I've put the '/' and now it works! Thank you.

Comment: I just thought that that was a typo. Nice to know that your problem is now solved.

Comment: yes, but the code generated on the file is not what I want. So, the purpose is to compare all the "g_place" on the current group with all the "g_place" of the previous group, so that in the end if there is any match, I use "Elsif". Is there any way, instead of using "for-each", to get all the "g_place" of the current group and compare with all the "g_place" of previous group? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "sibling" and add a "/" in your XPath :

```
//group[@id="1"]//g_place[@id="3"]/preceding::group[1]//g_place
```

returns 2 nodes.

Comment: Hi, I also tried your solution and it didn't work either.